# How to handle null values when importing to CRM Online?

Tags: microsoft-excel, dynamics-crm

I have an Excel file of accounts which is imported from a previous CRM version (2011), and I would like to import it to CRM Online. Some columns that hold integer values might also contain “null” in case the value does not exist.

These null values are causing errors and doesn’t allow the row to be imported, it displays the message “The source data is not in the required format.” How can I get around this and let the CRM ignore the cell data when “null” and not try to insert it into the CRM?

Comment: Are your 'null' columns containing 'null' as text or are they empty? If this is the case just replace the text with empty column. There shouldn't be a problem importing empty columns. If there still is a problem filter out these fields in excel and do a separate import for the ones that have a value and the ones that don't.

Comment: That was the problem, changing the null cells to blank fixed it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @BojanBorisovski It would be better if your answer is posted as an answer and the original poster would accept it. Could you copy-paste your comment as an answer and maybe rephrase it as an answer (instead of a suggestion/question)?

Comment: I have posted the same comment as answer. @agtoever thanks for the suggestion. user3340627 I am glad it could help. Please accept my newly posted answer (the same as the comment) as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your 'null' columns containing 'null' as text or are they empty?

If this is the case just replace the text with empty column. There shouldn't be a problem importing empty columns.

If there still is a problem filter out these fields in excel and do a separate import for the ones that have a value and the ones that don't.